# mongodb async operation failing with express nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am learning Nodejs to mongodb connectivity i tried below code but i am not getting desired output

**MongoDbConnectivity.js:**

```
// Connect using a MongoClient instance
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const test = require("assert");
const logger = require("./loggers");
// Connection url
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
// Database Name
const dbName = "test";
// Connect using MongoClient
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url);
//function getData() {
async function getData() {
  mongoClient.connect(async function (err, client) {
    const db = client.db(dbName);

    try {
      const Mainresult = await db
        .collection("employeeDetails")
        .find({})
        .toArray()
        .then((result) => {
          return result;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          logger.errorLog(err);
          return err;
          console.log(err);
        });
      console.log(Mainresult); //I am getting Output in Console
      return Mainresult;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  });
}

module.exports.getData = getData;
```

**NodeJS express code :**

```
 var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var config = require("./config.json");
    const logger = require("./loggers");
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const mongoDb = require("./MongoDbConnectivity");
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // app.use(
    //   cors({
    //     methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
    //   })
    // );
    app.use(cors());
    app.get("/getEmployees",async function (req, res) {
      console.log("before hitting the Mongo");
     // var employeeData = mongoDb.getData().then((result) => {
      //  return result;
     // });
var employeeData =await mongoDb.getData();
      console.log("After hitting the Mongo");
      console.log("from Node:" + employeeData);
      res.send(employeeData);
    });
    
    var mongoServer = app.listen(5000, function () {
      logger.infoLog(
        "Server Started at :" +
          new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/New_York" })
      );
      console.log("Server is running..");
    });
```

**My console output is:**

> Server is running.. before hitting the Mongo After hitting the Mongo
> from Node:undefined

**I am not getting the desired output which is mongodb documnets instead i am getting this undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Your **getData** is a Promise. Therefore, you need to call this method with **await** and change the callback function to **async** in the route of express.

From:

```
function (req, res)
```

To:

```
async function (req, res)
```

From:

```
var employeeData = mongoDb.getData()
```

To:

```
var employeeData = await mongoDb.getData()
```

Result:

```
app.get("/getEmployees", async function (req, res) {
  var employeeData = await mongoDb.getData();
  res.send(employeeData);
});
```

Comment: After adding those changes now i am getting undefined
Server is running..
before hitting the Mongo
After hitting the Mongo
from Node:undefined

Comment: @pranayrebel Sorry. I edited the result to the correct code. This happens because **then** return undefined.

Comment: i am still getting undefined after removing **then**